# Python matplotlib: Add legend for a colormap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and I am trying to recreate a figure like the following which is a log-log figure:

[image]

I know that I have to use colormap to create such output based on my x and y values. What I can not figure is how to add the legend so it can calculates the values for the colormap variable (e.g. here called "Degree") dynamically. Here is what I've got for a sample figure so far:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [125, 32, 54, 253, 67, 87, 233, 56, 67]

color = [str(item/255.) for item in y]

plt.scatter(x, y, s=500, c=color)

plt.show()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Sajjan gave you a full answer, what you are asking for is `plt.colorbar()'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign an appropriate colormap for your plot, in this case a grayscale colormap:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y = [125, 32, 54, 253, 67, 87, 233, 56, 67]

color = [item / 255.0 for item in y]
grayscale_map = plt.get_cmap('gray')

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 500, c = color, cmap = grayscale_map)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that I changed your `color` list to list of floats that will (presumably) range from 0 to 1.

Comment: Is it possible to add the labels next to the color bar on the right? I would like to have it labeled only at the extremes and ideally with some text. For example, the label '0' would be replaces by '$x=0$' and the label '1' by '$x=1$'

Comment: I have found a solution in the meantime, so for anyone searching, visit [this answer][1] . By adding or removing elements in 'cmaps' one can adjust the number of different inputs.

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501860/how-to-put-multiple-colormap-patches-in-a-matplotlib-legend

Comment: You can set the tick labels of a colorbar, as this mpl demo shows: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/colorbar_tick_labelling_demo.html